axes titles not displaying on pgfplot
i'm new to latex, and was recently using pgfplots, but wanted to label everything so i went back and used x label style, y label style, xlabel, and ylabel to display labels. the code for my labels work in most pgfplots i have but not this one (and i don't know why):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scatter/classes={a={mark=*,draw=black}}]
\addplot
[
draw=black,
scatter,
mark size=2.1pt,
scatter src=explicit symbolic,
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},anchor=south},
xlabel={Data Set $S(a,X)$},
ylabel={Cumulative Relative Frequency $(\%)$}
]
table
[
meta=label
]
{
x y label
1 .05 a
7 .15 a
9 .25 a
11 .35 a
13 .45 a
25 .55 a
27 .65 a
29 .75 a
31 .85 a
47 .95 a
}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}


(sorry if code is messy) this is all that gets outputted though. any help on how to display the axes? thank you.

If you didn't notice in the (correct) Arne's answer, the problem is that the axis labels, title, etc. options should go in axis options, not in the addplot ones. Moreover, you need a compact flag (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}) or similar, look at the warning.

Try something like this:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstableread{
x y 
1 .05 
7 .15 
9 .25 
11 .35 
13 .45 
25 .55 
27 .65 
29 .75 
31 .85 
47 .95 
}\tableCRF
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title= blabla,
    ylabel near ticks,
    xlabel near ticks,
    xlabel={Data Set $S(a,X)$},
    ylabel={Cumulative Relative Frequency $(\%)$},
    scatter/classes={a={mark=*,draw=black}}]
\addplot[mark=*, mark size = 1pt] table{\tableCRF};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}


